# Created hosts and host instances, but can not choose them in the receive location

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I've created hosts, and host instances,  which are running, but I can't see them in the receive handler drop down.  Is there an additional step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will also need to create a new Send and/or Receive Handler in the Adapters section of Platform Settings.  This instructs the individual process (Host Instance) to load an instance of the Adapter Handler into the process space.

You will then be able to select the Send or Receive Handler in the drop-down in your port configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter handlers are bound to a BizTalk Host instance, and BizTalk Host instances are bound to a BizTalk server.

An adapter handler is an instance of a BizTalk host in which the adapter code runs. When you specify a send or receive handler for an adapter you are specifying which host instance the adapter code will run in the context of. An adapter handler is responsible for executing the adapter and contains properties for a specific instance of an adapter. A default BizTalk Server configuration will create adapter handlers for all of the installed adapters.

For the host instance which you create, in order to Host to be visible inside the Send / Receive Handlers, you have to link the Host with the Adapters.

This is done by Expanding Platform Settings -> Adapters -> Right Clicking any Adapter -> New Send / Receive Handler.

Now, add the Host to the handler.

Now it will be visible in the Send/Receive Handlers.

All adapter handlers except for HTTP and SOAP adapter receive handlers must be configured to run in an in-process host. HTTP and SOAP adapter receive handlers can only be run in an isolated host.